# How many Google Adsense Ads for Multilingual Website

Tags: google-adsense, multilingual

For a multilingual website is it better (in terms of income) to have an ad that serves each language or only one ad that serves all languages?

I know that Google adsense knows how to get the language of the page, and this question is not about that it's about the organisation of the ads. All ads are responsive.

Trying to rephrase the question, if I have one ad for all languages it will have more views does it make it more interesting for advertisers?

Answer (score 1):

Google Adsense doesn't just get the language of the 'page', it gets the language preference of the visitor's browser.  And of course, Google makes use of the visitor's browser history when serving ads.

So no, there's absolutely no need to use multiple ads for different languages.

Comment: Thank you, I'm aware of the language independence of the adsense ads, the question is about the views, or whether it's better to have one ad or 3 ads? if they are all responsive there shouldn't be a problem (in theory) to use only one ad for all cases. In my case I'm using one ad/language, but somebody else could use one ad/ logical section. The question is how to structure the responsive ads, is it better to have several or is better to have only a few (e.g. one). Does it make any difference for the income/the way the advertisers perceive the ads on that particular website?

Answer (score 0):

You won't need multiple ads just to solve the audience that comes in. Because Google AdSense will deliver the ads identifying the behavior, geolocation and other preferences used by the user. The ads may or may not be in their favourite language depending up on their preferences.

**Cut short**
Google will handle the multilingual ad part. You just need to give it a space to display.